# Object is not being sent over a socket

Tags: java, sockets, object, server, client

This is driving me nuts. Between the object containing a Buffered Image and trying to implement a server client system into a game updating and rendering 60 times a second, I got completely lost. I thought I was doing everything right, so I isolated the server client system, and cannot seem to send a object over a socket.

The program seems to get stuck and not proceed when trying to receive an object.

the specific spot the code is catching on is:

```
Troops troop2 = (Troops)c.receiveObject();
```

as deduced by System.out.print's. The rest of the code is below, no errors are being thrown, and I run Interfacer and Interfacer2.

```
public class Interfacer{
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Client c = new Client();
        System.out.println("it ran 1/2...client");
        while(true){
            Troops troop2 = (Troops)c.receiveObject();  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, troop2.getX());
            System.out.println("it ran...client");
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}





public class Interfacer2{
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Server s = new Server();
        Troops troop = new Goblin(1,1,1);
        s.sendObject(troop);
        System.out.println("it ran...server");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class Client extends JFrame{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;

JTextArea t;
JFrame f;

//constructor
public Client(String host){

    serverIP = host;

    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.pack();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new JTextArea();
    f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setVisible(true);

    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        //t.append("Connection was terminated");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public Client(){

    serverIP = "127.0.0.1";

    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.pack();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new JTextArea();
    f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setVisible(true);


    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        //t.append("Connection was terminated");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}



//connect to server
private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    t.append("Attempting connection...");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 7382);
    t.append("Connection Established! Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//set up streams
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    t.append(" The streams are now set up!");
}


//Close connection
public void closeConnection(){
    //t.append(" Closing the connection!");
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendObject(Object o) throws IOException{
    output.writeObject(o);
    output.flush();
}
public Object receiveObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    return input.readObject();  
}

}


public class Server{



private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

JTextArea t;
JFrame f;

//constructor
public Server(){


    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new JTextArea();
    f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setVisible(true);

    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(7382, 100); //6789 is a dummy port for testing, this can be changed. The 100 is the maximum people waiting to connect.
        while(true){
            try{
                //Trying to connect and have conversation
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                //t.append("Connection was terminated");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//wait for connection, then display connection information
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    t.append(" Waiting for someone to connect...");
    connection = server.accept();
    t.append(" Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();

    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    t.append(" Streams are now setup ");
}


        //  input.readObject();


public void closeConnection(){
    //t.append(" Closing Connections... ");
    try{
        output.close(); //Closes the output path to the client
        input.close(); //Closes the input path to the server, from the client.
        connection.close(); //Closes the connection between you can the client
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void sendObject(Object o) throws IOException{
    output.writeObject(o);
    output.flush();
}
public Object receiveObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    return input.readObject();  
}

}


public class Troops implements Serializable{
private int x;
private int y;


private int health;
private int movSpeed;
private int movSpeedx;
private int movSpeedy;
private int cost;
private long deployCoolDown;
private int level;
private transient BufferedImage image;
private int size = 16;
/**
 * 
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param level
 * @param health
 * @param movSpeed
 * @param movSpeedx
 * @param movSpeedy
 * @param cost
 * @param deployCoolDown
 * @param image
 * 
 */

public Troops(int x, int y, int level, int health, int movSpeed, int movSpeedx, int movSpeedy, int cost, long deployCoolDown, BufferedImage image){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.level = level;
    this.health = health;
    this.movSpeed = movSpeed;
    this.movSpeedx = -movSpeed;
    this.movSpeedy = movSpeedy;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.deployCoolDown = deployCoolDown;
    this.image = image;

}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public int getSize(){
    return size;
}
public int getMovSpeed() {
    return movSpeed;
}
public void setMovSpeed(int movSpeed) {
    this.movSpeed = movSpeed;
}
public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void changeHealth(int health) {
    this.health += health;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public long getDeployCoolDown() {
    return deployCoolDown;
}

public void setDeployCoolDown(int deployCoolDown) {
    this.deployCoolDown = deployCoolDown;
}

 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)throws IOException{
     out.defaultWriteObject();
     //write buff with imageIO to out
 }

 private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
     in.defaultReadObject();
     //read buff with imageIO from in
 }


}
```

here is the place I got the transient and readObject/writeObject part of the troop class:

[Java - Sending an object that points to a BufferedImage through a Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031481/java-sending-an-object-that-points-to-a-bufferedimage-through-a-socket)

Comment: Show the code for `Troop`.  By definition `transient` fields do not get serialized.

Comment: 'Cannot seem to send' is not a problem descripton. Unclear what you're asking. The `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods you've posted are pointless. Remove them. Exactly the same thing happens by default.

Comment: I updated the question, as well as putting a link to where I found the wrtite/readObject() methods. I would give a better problem description, but there are no errors being thrown and I do not know enough about sockets to figure out why there is an issue. I've also tried sending in a simpler object such as a string, but got the same results.

Comment: You still haven 't posted an actual problem. What is happening that you don't expect? Or not happening that you do expect?

Comment: I edited it to be more clear on what is (not) happening, I apologize for not being explicit enough

Comment: It still isn't clear. I had to run it myself to see what was happening. Shouldn't have to do that. You should have stated clearly that the client was blocked in `receiveObject()`.

Comment: I could only say where the problem was based off of the System.out.prints, as :                                                                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, troop2.getX());
 System.out.println("it ran...client");                                                                                         never was reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `Server` contains a `while` loop which doesn't exit until an `IOException` other than `EOFException` has been caught, so your `Interfacer2` class can never get to the next line where it calls `s.sendObject()`.

Poor design. Constructors should construct objects, not engage in infinite loops or network I/O.

Comment: That was the problem. I was using this code from a tutorial for a instant messenger, and I guess I only removed the while loop in client and forgot to do it in server. I really appreciate the help